# Tables with interfaces are not created in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework to create tables on sql management studio locally for now.

```
  public class Task
{

    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }


    public virtual List<IAlgorithmResult> AlgorithmResults { get; set; }

    public BodyRegions BodyRegion { get; set; }

    public ModalityTechnicalData ModalityData { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfSlices { get; set; }


}

public interface IAlgorithmResult
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string AlgorithmVersion { get; set; }
}

  public class ChestPluginResult : IAlgorithmResult, IValidationResult
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Pathologies> PathologiesFound { get; set; }

    public bool IsSupressNodulesPlugin { get; set; }
    public string AlgorithmVersion { get; set; }
}

  public interface IValidationResult
{
//marker interface
}

public abstract class ModalityTechnicalData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double Resolution { get; set; }

}

   public class CTTechnicalData : ModalityTechnicalData
{

    public int Radiation { get; set; }

    public double SliceThickness { get; set; }

    public double Gap { get; set; }

    public double SliceGap { get; set; }

    public string FilterType { get; set; }

    public bool IsContrastAgent { get; set; }



}
```

The task table is created, the ModalityTechnicalData  is created, no exception is thrown, but the chestPluginResult table is not created.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where's ModalityTechnicalData ?

Comment: Is ChestPluginResult set up in your DbContext?

Comment: EF can't map `public virtual List<IAlgorithmResult>`. It must be a concrete type.

Comment: Yes,  Rhumborl. Added, artm. TX

Comment: Thank you very much Arnold, the interface was the problem, though, The list does not have to be a concrete type, an abstract class will do just fine.